# Page always read the "NL" resource even if the CurrentCulture was changed to "EN"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, cultureinfo

I am trying to create a page with multi-language option in VB.net.
The files are as follows:

```
Page (Folder)
- Sample.aspx
- Sample.aspx.vb
- App_LocalResources
- - Sample.aspx.nl.resx
- - Sample.aspx.nl.resx
```

The culture in web.config is as follows:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" uiCulture="nl" culture="nl" enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>
```

Then, on the `Sample.aspx.vb`, I am trying to change the culture to "EN" but it still shows the "NL" text.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As System.EventArgs)
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en")
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en")
End Sub
```

I also tried putting it in Page_Load but it did not work.
I tried to put a break on the code behind, it seems the the culture is changing but still shows the "NL" text. I already searched in www, but I did not find any solutions.

I am hoping the you can help me with this. What is the best solution? Should I just set the labels from code behind?

Comment: You shouldn't add superfluous tag, like C#.

Comment: @PalleDue I'm doing it both in VB.Net and C#.

Comment: Your code only shows VB, so you are most likely to get answers from the VB crowd.

Comment: It looks like you use ASP.NET WebForms. You need to override the [InitializeCulture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture?view=netframework-4.8) method instead of `OnInit`.

Comment: @PalleDue Yes. I mean, I can convert the VB to C#. But thank you for the reminder. :D I appreciate it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes. I do use Webforms. Can you give me an example on how to try to do it?

Comment: This is explained in [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bz9tc508(v=vs.100)). You can configure ASP.NET to automatically use the language specified by the browser by setting the culture settings to `auto`, eg `<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto"`/>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Tried the link above and it worked. It already read the "en" resx when I override the InitializeCulture. Thank you. You saved me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way ASP.NET WebForms treats culture is explained in [How to: Set the Culture and UI Culture for ASP.NET Web Page Globalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bz9tc508(v=vs.100)).

First of all, the culture can be set either in `web.config` or at the page level with :

```
<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />
```

or

```
<%@ Page UICulture="es" Culture="es-MX" %>
```

It's also possible to set the culture based on the `Accept-Language` header sent by the browser by setting the culture to `auto` :

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
```

Finally, to modify the request's culture programmatically, override the `InitializeCulture` method:

```
Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en")
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en")
End Sub
```

This is useful when the browser doesn't send an `Accept-Language` header or when we want to apply our own logic, using eg geolocation to determine the language if `Accept-Language` is missing

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. But I did not change the config file to "auto". I just override the InitializeCulture() for the specific page because I only want to work the multi-language in some pages but not the whole application.